# How Do I Support Empty RouteAttribute in Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have this class:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/v2/Foo")]
public class SomeController : BaseController
{
    [Route("")]
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get(SomeEnum? param)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

I want to call it via:
`api/v2/Foo?param=Bar`
but it doesn't work.

If I change the routing attribute thusly to include something in the RouteAttribute:

```
    [Route("SomeRoute")]
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get(SomeEnum? param)
    {
        //...
    }
```

...then I *can* call
`api/v2/Foo/SomeRoute?param=Bar`
, but that isn't what I want.

How do I get the first circumstance to work?

EDIT:
Domas Masiulis steered me toward the answer: the above scenario DOES work, it's just that a default global routing screwed things up. I solved the issue by adding a separate default routing that matched our convention...

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        //ADDING THIS FIXED MY ISSUE
        routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "API Default",
            routeTemplate: "api/v2/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        //SOURCE OF THE ORIGINAL PROBLEM
        routes.MapRoute(
           "Default", // Route name
           "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
           new { controller = "Administration", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
       );
    }
```

Comment: You can simply use [Route("api/v2/Foo")] on your Get method, have you tried?

Comment: can this work "api/v2/Foo/Bar" ?

Comment: @RicardoPontual - I did try that and it didn't work. :-(

Comment: @Prashant - No. That routing is reserved for something else (and I'm curious about the answer to this specific circumstance, not a workaround)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Any special conditions? Maybe something hidden in BaseController? Any custom configurations in RouteConfig?

Your given example works for me, made a quick test:

Used code:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/v2/Foo")]
public class SomeController : ApiController
{
    [Route("")]
    [HttpGet]
    public Task<int> Get(int param)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(2);
    }
}
```

Calling 
http://localhost:1910/api/v2/Foo?param=1 works as expected - returns 2.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. It did turn out that something someone did with route mappings on application startup was screwing things up.

Answer (score 0):

1) You have to specify [FromUri] attribute for query parameter

2) If you use nullable parameter like SomeEnum? setup a default value for it

```
[Route("")]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get([FromUri] SomeEnum? param = null)
{
    //...
}
```